# Java: Accessing a File from an FTP Server

Tags: java, file, url, ftp

So I have this FTP server with a bunch of folders and files inside.

My program needs to access this server, read all of the files, and display their data.

For development purposes I've been working with the files on my hard drive, right in the "src" folder.

But now that the server is up and running, I need to connect the software to it.

Basically what I want to do is get a list of the Files in a particular folder on the server.

This is what I have so far:

```
URL url = null;
File folder = null;
try {
    url = new URL ("ftp://username:password@www.superland.example/server");
    folder = new File (url.toURI());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
data = Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles(new FileFilter () {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory();
    }
}));
```

But I get the error "URI scheme is not 'file'."

I understand this is because my URL starts with "ftp://" and not "file:"

However I can't seem to figure out what I'm supposed to do about it!

Maybe there's a better way to go about this?

Comment: And this question has been asked many times; perhaps one of the other answers will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+Accessing+a+File+from+an+FTP+Server

Comment: Do you want to be helpful, or cynical?
I was hoping. The thing is that I need a list of files.
I don't know any other way to go about this.

Comment: Not sure if you can using a URL.  You might want to look at a dedicated FTP library like Apache Net Commons or edtFTP4j

Comment: I tried using edtFTPj/Free but once I got to `FTPFile [] files = ftp.directoryList();` it froze for a minute or so and said "Read timed out." I guess I probably should start a thread on that, instead.

Comment: @RichYoung you have to be careful, as some ftp servers don't allow directory listings.  It depends on the platform (IBM, Sun, Windows) and how it's configured.  Since there's no real standard way to output directory listings, the ftp clients depend on parsers, and even then, they make educated guesses as to which platform they are talking to.  I use Net Commons (commons net?) mostly, as it is very simple to get up and running, but mainly because of their FTPS support.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`File` objects cannot handle an `FTP` connection, you need to use a `URLConnection`:

```
URL url = new URL ("ftp://username:password@www.superland.example/server");
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = urlc.getInputStream();
...
```

Consider as an alternative `FTPClient` from [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) which has support for many protocols. Here is an [FTP list files example](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/357.html).

Comment: The thing about a URLConnection is that I can only get an InputStream from it. If I could use that InputStream to then get a list of the files, sure...

Comment: Looking at the example, on line 13 it says `client.connect("ftp.server.com");` but I get an error when I try this, it says this method is undefined for FTPClient.

Comment: That method is [definitely there](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html#connect(java.lang.String)). Do you have the correct import?

Comment: My bad, I imported wrong. I hate using third-party code.

But now I'm trying listFiles() and it takes like five minutes to load, and comes up with nothing.

Answer (score 3):

if you use URI with file you can use your code but , but when you want to use ftp so you need to this kind of code; code list the name of the files under your ftp server

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("ftp://username:password@www.superland.example/server");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

**EDITED** [Demo Code Belongs to Codejava](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/using-urlconnection-to-list-files-and-directories-on-ftp-server)

```
package net.codejava.ftp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class FtpUrlListing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ftpUrl = "ftp://%s:%s@%s/%s;type=d";
        String host = "www.myserver.com";
        String user = "tom";
        String pass = "secret";
        String dirPath = "/projects/java";

        ftpUrl = String.format(ftpUrl, user, pass, host, dirPath);
        System.out.println("URL: " + ftpUrl);

        try {
            URL url = new URL(ftpUrl);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line = null;
            System.out.println("--- START ---");
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            System.out.println("--- END ---");

            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The server folder, right now, has only test.txt in it.

When I do this I get the following output:
`drwx---rwx    2 trucker2   inetuser         4096 Jan 22 12:40 .
drwx---r-x   10 trucker2   inetuser         4096 Jan 22 10:53 ..
-rw----r--    1 trucker2   inetuser            8 Jan 22 12:40 test.txt`
So how do I use this to read the files... ?

Comment: These code list the name of the files under your directory,actually it lists . current directory, .. parent directory and your test.txt if you want to get more details about these files you can check Edited link.