# issue with URL with String in java

Tags: java, url, exception

i have issue with URL object in java when i trying to do this code:

```
URL url = new URL("FTP://myname:mypassword@myServerIp/imagename.PNG;type=i");
```

i get an exception error (MalformedURLException)
i think this problem because my String have &,@ but i'm not sure about this.

when i trying another String URL it's work fine.
for example :

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
```

also i tried to Encoding my String with this code

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode(myString, "utf-8");
        URL url = new URL(query);
```

and get same exception error.

can you help me please ?

log file :

> 12-28 14:03:41.259: W/Exception Error(7383): Protocol not found: ftp%3A%2F%2Frsd48Image%3Asbol%3Fk63test%40192.111.7.17%2F20131228_140341.PNG%3Btype%3Di
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: ftp%3A%2F%2Frsd48Image%3Asbol%3Fk63test%40192.111.7.17%2F20131228_140341.PNG%3Btype%3Di
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at java.net.URL.(URL.java:178)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at java.net.URL.(URL.java:127)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at com.rsd48.mygooglemap.FileUpload.upload(FileUpload.java:69)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at com.rsd48.mygooglemap.add_comment.onActivityResult(add_comment.java:103)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5231)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3172)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3219)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:134)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
>   12-28 14:03:41.259: W/System.err(7383):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-28 14:03:50.558: W/System.err(7383): org.json.JSONException: No value for formatted_address
>   12-28 14:03:50.558: W/System.err(7383):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
>   12-28 14:03:50.558: W/System.err(7383):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
>   12-28 14:03:50.558: W/System.err(7383):     at com.rsd48.mygooglemap.LocationName.getJSON(LocationName.java:30)
>   12-28 14:03:50.558: W/System.err(7383):     at com.rsd48.mygooglemap.Map$1.run(Map.java:246)
>   12-28 14:03:50.558: W/System.err(7383):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>   12-28 14:03:50.558: W/System.err(7383):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   12-28 14:03:50.558: W/System.err(7383):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   12-28 14:03:50.558: W/System.err(7383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
>   12-28 14:03:50.558: W/System.err(7383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-28 14:03:50.568: W/System.err(7383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   12-28 14:03:50.568: W/System.err(7383):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
>   12-28 14:03:50.568: W/System.err(7383):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
>   12-28 14:03:50.568: W/System.err(7383):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467107/java-accessing-a-file-from-an-ftp-server

Comment: This line alone does not give `MalformedUrlException`. Please provide extra trace logs. And yes, doing `URLEncoder.encode(myString, "utf-8")` will result in that exception because of replacement of / to %.

Comment: log file is attached..

Comment: can you post the log for the case when you don't use `URLEncoder.encode(myString, "utf-8");` for the same url ?

Comment: thank you, the problem is solved,
the username and the password should not have any special characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` character is not valid in that position in the URL.

Comment: That's not right. The RFC only says that ":", "@", or "/" must be encoded if they are contained in the username or password part. See section 3.1 of rfc 1738.

Comment: @ReneLink No, it doesn't 'only' say that. It also says that various characters including the ones you mention may be reserved within a scheme, and that characters reserved within a scheme must be encoded (#2.1). For example, & would have to be encoded within an HTTP URL argument name or value.